# Is there a full list of Kubernetes controller names inside the kube-system namespace that are owned by Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I am aware that there is a kube-system namespace, and users are not expected to modify or create any objects in this namespace as it is not intended for user use. However, I would like to verify this in our system. Is there a full list of Kubernetes controller names inside the kube-system namespace that are owned by Kubernetes, such as kube-dns and kube-proxy? I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide an official Kubernetes document related to this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.